# SmoothFollow2D tweak

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've applied this standard assets script to my camera for a 2D game and it's actually doing a good job but since my background texture is placed inside a quad that "follows" the player and not the camera at higher movement speed the camera gets too far or too much behind the player and gets out of view.

Since I never programmed in JS I'd like to ask you how should I tweak this code to stop the script from moving the camera if the velocity is over (for example) 5f.

I tried to change it this way :

```
var target : Transform;
var smoothTime = 0.3;
private var thisTransform : Transform;
private var velocity : Vector2;



function Start()
{
   thisTransform = transform;
}



function Update()

{

   if(velocity.x > 5f) //in C# I'd do it this way, but apparently

   velocity.x = 5f; //this is not stopping the camera from getting out of game-sight


   thisTransform.position.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp( thisTransform.position.x,
   target.position.x, velocity.x, smoothTime);
   thisTransform.position.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp( thisTransform.position.y,
   target.position.y, velocity.y, smoothTime);

}
```

This possibly happens because i'm actually passing a reference as a parameter (velocity.x called as a reference http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

If you want to set your camera's max speed, Mathf.SmoothDamp() can set maxSpeed.

```
var maxSpeed : float = 5.0f;
Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, target.position.x, velocity.x, smoothTime, maxSpeed);
```

Comment: MaxSpeed just sets the max reacheable speed of the camera before stopping following the player. The problem is that after a certain speed, the player gets out of sight, since the camera moves too much

Comment: Because your code looks like you don't want camera move too fast. If you want camera to follow player and don't let player out of sight, maybe you could try Mathf.Lerp()